# Twitter and Facebook IDP having no E-mail in Firebase, how to get unique id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication, firebaseui

Using the FirebaseUI I have a question about Twitter and Facebook IDP.

Since this two can be signed in only using a phone number I was thinking,, In Firebase at the Authentication user panel if I have a user sign in with gmail, I can use that gmail(test1@gmail.com) as an internal id for the user since its considered a [Trusted provider(right)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/liu/firebase-talk/ms_NVQem_Cw/8g7BFk1IAAAJ) Now when the above two bad boys sign in with phone number my question is, is it safe to use the:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
```

as a secure user identifier, if I never let the user delete and recreate his Firebase user account?

Note in Firebase I have set the "One account per email address"

Am I on the wrong path here!? How to think about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the UID is safe to use as a secure identifier - it is unique per user in your project, regardless of sign-in method.